# Proving an upper bound to F(x)+G(x)

Tags: proof-writing, upper-lower-bounds

I have stumbled upon the following question: If $f(x),g(x) > 1$ for every $x$, prove/disprove the following:

$$f(x)+g(x)= O\left(f(x)g(x)\right)$$

I dont know how to start the proof, this is very basic for my level, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write down the definition of the Landau notation and then use the triangular inequality.